# Elementor custom category not showing up in edit panel

Tags: elementor

Im trying to build a custom Elementor widget in my own category, but when I created a custom category, it was not displayed in the edit panel, which means I have to search my widget name to find it.

Does any know how to fix it?

The code:

```
function add_elementor_widget_categories() {

    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->$elements_manager->add_category(
        'category-name',
        [
            'title' => __( 'Test Category', 'plugin-name' ),
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-plug',
        ]
    );

}
add_action( 'elementor/elements/categories_registered', 'add_elementor_widget_categories' );
```

This code is from Elementor sample code, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I found solution. Need to add add_action to function __construct()

Comment: Add your code as an answer. I couldn't understand what you meant.